# MATLAB - The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions

Tags: matlab, parsing, evaluation

I am trying to evaluate a formula given in a text file.

```
fid = fopen('ReactionFlux.txt')
EqRF = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', {'\n'});
fclose(fid);

syms Chyl_gi Chyl_ly_release_rate_k

eval(EqRF{1}{1})
```

The context of text file ReactionFlux.txt is

```
ReactionFlux33 = Chyl_gi*Chyl_ly_release_rate_k
```

Yet everytime that I try to evaluate the line here, it gives the error

```
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

Is there a hidden whitespace character that is invalid or something?

Comment: What is `textscan` actually returning?

Comment: It works for me. You also might try `strtrim` around the string to get rid of any invisible glyphs.

Comment: @drhagen that did the trick.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `textscan` will pull up invisible glyphs that are in the file. You can get usually get rid of them by wrapping the extracted line in `strtrim`, which gets rid of all whitespace at the beginning and end of a string:

```
eval(strtrim(EqRF{1}{1}))
```